# hibernate jpa java.lang.ClassCastException: model.Dog cannot be cast to model.Dog

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, classnotfoundexception

I have a weird exception and I can't tell why. I have the list in memory from the database but when I try to access the getters or to save the entity in a variable it throws an exception.

Here is the entity:

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Dog.findAll", query="SELECT d FROM Dog d")
public class Dog implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    public Dog() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

this is my session bean implementation:

```
@Stateless(name = "mytable")
public class TableBean implements TableLocal {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "sample")
private EntityManager manager;

@Override
public Dog getAll() {
    Dog h = manager.find(Dog.class, 1); 
    Hibernate.initialize(h);
    return h;
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Dog> findAll() {
    Query query = manager.createQuery("SELECT h FROM Dog h",Dog.class);
    List<Dog> col = query.getResultList();
    Hibernate.initialize(col);
    return col;
}

@Override
public void addDog() {
    Dog d = new Dog();
    //d.setId(2);
    d.setName("chappy");
    manager.persist(d);
}
}
```

I have also a service bean, but it's pointless

```
@Stateless(name = "service")
public class ServiceBean implements ServiceLocal {

    @EJB(beanName = "mytable")
    TableLocal table;

    @Override
    public Dog getAll() {
        return table.getAll();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Dog> findAll() {
        return table.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void addDog() {
        table.addDog();

    }
}
```

and my servlet:

```
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EJB(beanName = "service")
    ServiceLocal table;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<Dog> tables = table.findAll();
        Iterator<Dog> it = tables.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Dog t = it.next();
            resp.getWriter().println(t.getName());
        }
        /*Dog h = table.getAll();
        resp.getWriter().println(h.getId() + " " + h.getName());*/
        /*table.addDog();
        resp.getWriter().println("Added!");*/
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(req, resp);
    }

}
```

and the erro is:

```
2015-07-28T13:38:17.385+0300|Warning: StandardWrapperValve[HelloServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet HelloServlet threw exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: model.Dog cannot be cast to model.Dog
    at HelloServlet.doGet(HelloServlet.java:26)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="sample">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>MySQL</jta-data-source>
        <class>model.Dog</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: That Looks like a classloder problem. Do you have the jar containing model.Dog class two times in your server classpath?

Comment: it might be that. I have a dependency in the web module for backend and also a dependency in server module for backend and web. Should I give the scope provided? I'm using maven for build and deploy on glassfish

Comment: Whare are both files located?

Comment: Which files do you mean?

Comment: The jars that contains `model.Dog`

Comment: I only have model.Dog in backend, and in the web pom I have a dependency for the backend with scope provided. And in the backend I have model.Dog

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have two jars:

- one for web
- one for the core services (e.g. EJBs)

Both jars include the `model.Dog` class and the application server loads two versions of the same class from two different sources. When the core layer sends the `model.Dog` response to the web layer the response has a class version loaded in the core layer while the web layer already has a different runtime version of that class, hence the exception you get.

To fix it, you need to include the entities only in the core layer and the web layer should have a dependency on the core layer artefact, instead of including the entities themselves.

### Update

Also remove this:

```
Hibernate.initialize(h);
```

As it doesn't bring any value in your particular use case.

Comment: in the web pom I have a dependency on backend with the scope provided. Where should I look for the jars?

Comment: In the packed war or ear. There you should simply search for `model.Dog` and see if there are two occurrences of that class.

Comment: it's only one occurence in the backend ejb module. In web module I don't have any model.Dog

Comment: I think it's hibernate, because I changed to use Eclipse Link and now it works

Comment: Check my update and try without `Hibernate.initialize()`

Comment: same error. Maybe my persistence.xml configuration is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your `findAll()` method, use TypedQuery instead of Query.
The reason is that, TypedQuery's `getResultList()` is returning list of typed list. i.e. in your case, `List<Dog>` but Query's getResultList is returning Raw `List`

You can try using below code:-

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Dog> findAll() {
    TypedQuery<Dog> query = manager.createQuery("SELECT h FROM Dog h",Dog.class);
    List<Dog> col = query.getResultList();
    Hibernate.initialize(col);
    return col;
}
```

Comment: The above solution of TypedQuery worked for me earlier.  One more thing, why you are again creating query since you already declared `@NamedQuery`.  Your code in `findAll()` should be like this,    `TypedQuery<Dog> query = manager.createQuery("Dog.findAll",Dog.class);
`

Comment: same error. Maybe my persistance.xml is wrong? I added to the question.